# Apache overriding root location directive and servicing files

Tags: apache-2.4

I run Node.js server on port 444, for document and API service, connected to apache server using `<Location />` directive and `ProxyPass` directrive. The connection itself works as perfect...

However, I would like Apache server to serve constant resources(images, icons) and files instead of passing request to node server. The files that I would like apache to serve are located under `https://example.com/*/resources/` and `https://example.com/files/`.

> How can I specify location and override `<Location />` to make apache serve files under specific url directory?

Here is my full Virtual host file...

```
Listen 443

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES
SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/www/apache24/data"
ServerName www.example.com:443
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd-error.log"
TransferLog "/var/log/httpd-access.log"

ProxyRequests Off
SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/etc/apache24/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/etc/apache24/server.key"
SSLCACertificateFile "/usr/local/etc/apache24/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "/usr/local/www/apache24/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

CustomLog "/var/log/httpd-ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

#    NODE.JS SERVER PROXY
#    Sends request to Node.js server running on localhost:444

<proxy *>
Allow from all
</proxy>

#<LocationMatch "/*/resources">
#AllowOverRide None
#</LocationMatch>
#
#<Location "/files">
#AllowOverRide None
#</Location>

<Location />
ProxyPass http://localhost:444/
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:444/
</Location>



</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Alias` directive to map URLs to the filesystem.

The `https://example.com/files/` is easy:

```
Alias "/files" "/the/dir/where/files/are/stored/files"
<Directory "/the/dir/where/files/are/stored/files">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

For the URL `https://example.com/*/resources/` is a little more complex as the * can match everything, and it will depend on how you want to organize the filesystem. In this case you can use the `AliasMatch`

One option would be:

```
AliasMatch "^/(.*)/resources/(.*)" "/the/dir/where/files/are/stored/$1/resources/$2"
<Directory "`/the/dir/where/files/are/stored/`">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

If you request `https://example.com/aaa/resources/bbbb.jpg` it will look for `/the/dir/where/files/are/stored/aaa/resources/bbbb.jpg`

But maybe you want to discard the `*` value or organize the files different:

```
AliasMatch "^/(.*)/resources/(.*)" "/the/dir/where/files/are/stored/resources/$1/$2"
<Directory "/the/dir/where/files/are/stored/resources">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

That way if you request `https://example.com/aaa/resources/bbbb.jpg` it will look for `/the/dir/where/files/are/stored/resources/aaa/bbbb.jpg`

More info at: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html